# MySQL - Reference main query in nested select (need to be nested)

Tags: mysql, session, variables, nested

I've been looking for this and I always get answers that change the way to do things, but do not solve the general question, which is: reference a main query variable in a nested SELECT.

I need it to be a nested query, as the data structure is quite complicated. Let's see the example I need to be done:

```
SET @teamg_id := 0;
SELECT 
    @teamg_id := player.team_id,
    player.team_id AS player_team, 
    event.local_team_id AS local_team, 
    event.visitor_team_id AS visitor_team, 
    action.unique_id AS action_id, 
    action.player_id AS player_id,
    player.name AS player_name,
    playerindex.rank AS player_pos, 
    playerindex.ses_var_nest AS ses_var_nest 
FROM  
    er_players player, 
    er_events event, 
    er_actions action 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        unique_id, team_id, @pn:=@pn+1 AS rank, @teamg_id AS ses_var_nest  
    FROM 
        er_players, (SELECT @pn:=-1) p2 
    WHERE 
        team_id = @teamg_id 
    ORDER BY 
        dorsal ASC, id DESC) playerindex 
ON 
    playerindex.unique_id = action.player_id 
WHERE 
    action.unique_id = '1374572622'  
    AND player.unique_id = action.player_id 
    AND event.unique_id = (SELECT event_id 
        FROM er_analysis 
        WHERE unique_id = action.analysis_id)
```

As you can see, I need to return the "index" of this player in his team, in the order it would be returned doing the query (the rank value), but I need it to be counted related to the team, not the whole *Players* table.

In order to do so, I need to reference the main query value "player.team_id" inside the nested SELECT - which I tried and haven't been able to do, so I ended using the session variable.

What I get from this query is that @teamg_id stores the value well in the main query, but when passed to the nested query its value turn to NULL:

```
@teamg_id  |  player_team  |  local_team  |  visitor_team  |  action_id   | player_id  |  player_name  |  player_pos  |  ses_var_nest

1374570040 |   1374570040  |  1374570040  |  1374571827    |  1374572622  | 1374570146 |   Player name |     NULL     |     NULL
```

**My question is how can I use a session variable - which I think should be working - in a nested query, or how to reference a main query value in it.**

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT: Here's the structure of the er_players table, which is the one giving me the problems.** If I say "give me index of 'Player 3'" it should give me 2 (0, 1, 2), because it's the third player in his team.

```
+------------+------------+----------+----------+--------+
| unique_id  |  team_id   |   name   | position | dorsal |
+------------+------------+----------+----------+--------+
| 1374570066 | 1374570040 | Player 1 | Defense  |      1 |
| 1374570034 | 1374570040 | Player 2 | Defense  |      2 |
| 1374677119 | 1374571827 | Player 7 | Position |      7 |
| 1374570146 | 1374570040 | Player 3 | Attack   |      5 |
+------------+------------+----------+----------+--------+
```

**EDIT 2 (SOLUTION): Found a solution thanks to Kordirko's answer and some playing.**

```
 SELECT 
        player.team_id AS player_team, 
        event.local_team_id AS local_team, 
        event.visitor_team_id AS visitor_team, 
        action.unique_id AS action_id, 
        action.player_id AS player_id,
        player.name AS player_name,
        playerindex.rank AS player_pos, 
        playerindex.ses_var_nest AS ses_var_nest 
    FROM  
        er_actions action 
    LEFT JOIN er_events event 
        ON event.unique_id = (SELECT event_id FROM er_analysis WHERE unique_id = action.analysis_id) 
    LEFT JOIN er_players player 
        ON player.unique_id = action.player_id 
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT 
            unique_id, team_id, team_id AS ses_var_nest ,
            case when team_id <> @lastteam
                then  (@pn:=-1)
            end AS hander, 
            case when team_id <> @lastteam
                then(@lastteam:=team_id) 
            end AS team_id_new, 
            @pn:=@pn+1 AS rank 
        FROM 
            er_players, (SELECT (@pn:=-1),(@lastteam:=0)) p2 
        ORDER BY 
            team_id, dorsal ASC, id DESC) playerindex 
    ON 
        playerindex.unique_id = action.player_id  
        AND playerindex.team_id = player.team_id   /* new join condition */     
    WHERE 
        action.unique_id = '1374572622'
```

Selecting the @rank after the CASES makes it not to be 0 twice, and to reset the @rank before the selection. Otherwise, it was turning to 0 but into the second player of each team.

Hope someone can find helpfull this question.

**Thanks to Kordirko again for his time and answers.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot work. 
SELECT clause is always evaluated at the end of the execution chain,
@teamg_id variable will always be 0 in the nested subquery.

Try this query, it is not tested (I can't see your data, playing whith sample data always helps), but probably it gives desired results.
I commented out some parts and add one join condition.

```
  /*  SET @teamg_id := 0; */
    SELECT 
        /* @teamg_id := player.team_id, */
        player.team_id AS player_team, 
        event.local_team_id AS local_team, 
        event.visitor_team_id AS visitor_team, 
        action.unique_id AS action_id, 
        action.player_id AS player_id,
        player.name AS player_name,
        playerindex.rank AS player_pos, 
        playerindex.ses_var_nest AS ses_var_nest 
    FROM  
        er_players player, 
        er_events event, 
        er_actions action 
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT 
            unique_id, team_id, @pn:=@pn+1 AS rank, team_id AS ses_var_nest ,
            case when team_id <> @lastteam
                 then  (@pn:=-1) <> (@lastteam:=team_id) end
        FROM 
            er_players, (SELECT (@pn:=-1),(@lastteam:=0)) p2 
     /*   WHERE 
            team_id = @teamg_id */
        ORDER BY 
            team_id, dorsal ASC, id DESC) playerindex 
    ON 
        playerindex.unique_id = action.player_id  
        AND playerindex.team_id = player.team_id /* new join condition */     
    WHERE 
        action.unique_id = '1374572622'  
        AND player.unique_id = action.player_id 
        AND event.unique_id = (SELECT event_id 
            FROM er_analysis 
            WHERE unique_id = action.analysis_id)
```

Comment: Hello Kordirko! Thank you very much for your answer. I was getting an error which I solved by LEFT JOINING all tables to the main one ("er_actions"), because player.team_id could not be referenced as it was the first table and not the JOINED one. It's working now, however I don't understand why, the counter does not turn to 0 when the team is different. Maybe you could find why, as I've not been able to do so - I think it should, as you're telling it to do. Thanks again for your time and answer!

Comment: I've found a suitable solution thanks to yours and a little playing by my part. Thank you very much again for your time and help! Without your answer, I wouldn't have made it!